# Changing path in environmental variables for R in Windows.

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to add following path to environmental variable on my PC (Works on 64 bit Windows 10).

Path : C:\R-3.2.5\bin\x64

when i run R.exe in command prompt i get the error "not recognised as internal or external command"(Truncated).

Whereas gcc --help works after adding rtoOls path to environmental variables.

I tried creating batch file it worked(but i checked just by giving path of R).

How do i solve this problem or should just go with adding other path to batch file and execute it every time ?

Apologies in case question is repeated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running a batch command? Are you running R or R CMD or R.exe? We need more to be able to help you

Comment: I was running R.exe after adding  C:\R-3.2.5\bin\x64 to environmental variables  on my PC. But it throws error. Then i tried different versions of R same situation occurred. So i created a batch command with the following path then R.exe worked                                                                                                       So I wanted to know what am i doing wrong while adding path to environmental variables? because batch  command is working, but not adding path to environmental variables . Also adding path of Rtools to environmental variables seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Admin Cmd Prompt and let me know if any errors:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "RPath=C:\R-3.2.5\bin\x64"                     
set "envPath=%PATH%" & set "Separator="
if not "%envPath:~-1%" == ";" set "Separator=;"

if "!envPath:%RPath%=!"=="%envPath%" (
    setx PATH "%PATH%%Separator%%RPath%" /M )
timeout 5
exit /b
```

Once you restart Cmd again, you should be able to run R.exe without any issues.